# Animation nodes bake to keyframes not working with polygon decomposed offsets

Tags: baking, animation-nodes

I have encountered problem baking my animation nodes to keyframes. I use polygon decomposition with offsets and they work perfectly fine. Whenever I try to bake to keyframes, everything but this gets baked properly. My project is big (3600 frames) and I cannot afford not to bake it, Blender crashes.[image: Node tree using polygon decomposition]

My only theory was that it does not work because of loop being used for offset objects, but lately I have found out that another object decomposed to polygons did not work either. Both objects are rendered as their originals used without any offset effects. Can this be the cause? And if so, how to prevent this? I would like to remove dependency to animation nodes. Thanks

EDIT: I have found answer, exporting objects to alembic file solves this. Now I encounter new problem, importing alembic files to blender crashes it when importing big .abc files. Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: Would you like to add your answer (it sound more like a workaround) as an actual answer post?

Comment: Welcome To Blender StackExchange! I think your alembic question is better suited as a bug report or as another question if you are sure it is not a bug.

Comment: Thanks, I have accepted Omar's answer and will post alembic as another question.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it may be possible if you bake the mesh into an alembic file, then import this file again into the blend file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Mesh Object Output* node does not support keyframe baking. A list of nodes that support keyframe baking are listed below:

- Cycles Material Output.
- Object Attribute Output.
- Object Data Path Output.
- Object Matrix Output.
- Object Transforms Output.
- Object Visibility Output.
- Shape Key Output.
- Text Sequence output. (Text input is not keyframe-able)
- Text Object Output. (Text input is not keyframe-able)
- Curve Object Output. (Splines input is not keyframe-able)

Comment: That is worth remembering and thank you for information. Omar, you should think of writing a book on Animation Nodes. Honestly, I'll be one of your first customers for your books.

Comment: @RitaGeraghty I think it is better if I incorporate all of the info in the Documentation itself, after all, the documentation is also available as a book. But let me know if you want to learn about something specific.

Comment: Thanks and ok, I will remember that in near future. I am gradually getting familiar with Animation Nodes, thanks to all your contributions and those by others. I am thereby learning usages of nodes.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it may be possible if you bake the mesh into an alembic file, then import this file again into the blend file.