# Animation nodes: bake Cycles Material Output to keyframes - possible?

Tags: animation, node-editor, animation-nodes

In an older Question I found an answer, what is possible to bake with AN.
One in the list was: Cycles Matrial Output (2 Years ago)

Link: [Animation nodes bake to keyframes not working with polygon decomposed offsets](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/121206/animation-nodes-bake-to-keyframes-not-working-with-polygon-decomposed-offsets)

I’ve a Plane with Emission-Node as Material, which changes Color and Strength randomly over time.

[image]

When I try to *Set Keyframes*, there is a problem (I believe):

In *Set Keyframes*-Node you need an object for reference to the data-path (custom-channel), but the material-datapath is not linked to a specific object (`bpy.data.materials["feuerlicht"].node_tree.nodes["Emission"].inputs[1].default_value`).

*Set Keyframes* node tells me

> `Could not set keyframe`

And when I look to python code, it seems, that I need an object for keyframe-setting:

`obj.keyframe_insert('location', frame=1)`

Or, as I found:

`material.node_tree.keyframe_insert(datapath, frame=1)`

But the material is not a separate object I can choose in then set keyframe-node, or?

I changed from Area-light to this plane-emission-thing to get it baked, I thought.

Is it possible to get Cycles-Material-changes baked to keyframes in AN?

Comment: Hi and welcome! Please add the link to the post you've found to your question. Also I recommend take the tour to learn about how this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Hi, thank you. I've edited the post with the link.

Comment: so, I think there does not exist a node for this. I made a quick and dirty script for this:

Answer (score 0):

After further search I think there is no node for this.
Now I did it with a quick an dirty script-node:

```
    # inputs:
# Enable = boolean
# SetKeyframes = boolean
# RemoveUnwanted = boolean
# MaterialName = text
# pframe = integer

import bpy

mat = None

if Enable:
    for tmat in bpy.data.materials:
        if tmat.name == MaterialName:
            mat = tmat
    if mat != None:
        print ('material found')
        emitStr = mat.node_tree.nodes['Emission'].inputs[1]
        if RemoveUnwanted:
            try:
                emitStr.keyframe_delete( 'default_value', frame=pframe)
            except:
                None
        if SetKeyframes:
            emitStr.keyframe_insert( 'default_value', frame=pframe)
            
    else:
        print ('material '+MaterialName+' not found')
        return
```